# QProcess::startDetached() but hide console window

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is it possible to run a program in Windows using `QProcess::startDetached()` while hiding its console window? `QProcess::start()` will hide the console window but `QProcess::startDetached()` does not, at least by default.

I could use `QProcess::start()` but then I'd have to wait for the child program to finish or the destructor would force-terminate it, and I want to close my program immediately after starting the child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and could not solve it in a clean way. I have found 2 options:

1. Hacky way: Subclass `QProcess` and call `setProcessState(QProcess::NotRunning);` after starting the process. This will prevent the destructor to terminate the process. But it relies on an implementation detail of `QProcess`
2. Create a memory leak: Dynamically create the `QProcess` on the heap, but never delete it, and thus never invoke its destructor

   ```
   {
       QProcess *process = new QProcess;
       process->start("taskkill", QStringList() << "/f" << "/im" << "My Service.exe");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the console using the Windows API.

First, `#include <windows.h>`.

Then call `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);`

somewhere in the detached process.